# Conditional update of vector

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I want to update a vector depending on its value:

If `f < 50`, then `x = f - 1`

If `f > 50`, then  `y = f + 1`

If `f == 50`, then set the value to zero

```
f <- seq(0, 100, by = 5)
```

I was trying to solve it with `if`, but the result wasn't good.

```
if (f<50)
{
  f = z
  x= z-1
  x
}
```

```
if (f>50)
{
  f = c
  y= c+1
  y
}
```

Comment: if is not *vectorised* and will only check the first element. `ifelse()` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use nested `ifelse` :

```
ifelse(f < 50, f - 1, ifelse(f > 50, f + 1, 0))
```

Or probably using `case_when` in which you can add multiple conditions.

```
dplyr::case_when(f < 50 ~ f - 1, 
                 f > 50 ~ f + 1, 
                 f == 50 ~ 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below

```
f-(f<50)-50*(f==50)+(f>50)
```

such that

```
> f-(f<50)+(f>50)
 [1]  -1   4   9  14  19  24  29  34  39  44  0  56  61  66  71  76  81  86  91
[20]  96 101
```

Comment: Similar but using `sign`: `(x + sign(x - 50)) * (x != 50)`

Comment: @Henrik Nice solution! Smart!